# No stack trace after crash

Tags: android

For some reason my Android application is no longer printing a stack trace to Logcat when my application crashes. This is making it extremely hard to debug exactly what is going on.

The only message I see now in Logcat when my applcaiton crashes is the following:

01-18 14:57:18.725 31333-31333/com.************ D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

I've had a look at many previous questions and answers on StackOverflow to try and get to the bottom of it, but no answers seem to solve my problem.

Has anyone else seen this problem before and been able to resolve it?

Comment: Did you applied some filters in your logcat? Or a search?

Comment: Nope, nothing like that unfortunately. I've had this problem for days now.

Comment: That's an error under the `debug` filter, have you tried switching it to the `error` filter in the dropdown?

Comment: Have you tried enabling and disabling the adb option in android studio?

tools > android > enable Adb integration - toggle this

Comment: ADB is enabled. I'm getting other log output in logcat, just not Uncaught Exceptions when my app crashes.

Comment: Having same problem, have you resolved it. my device is huawei honor 6x.

Comment: @Shivansh - I did. I needed to configure my Logcat so it was not being cleared after the app crashed as far as I remember. It was a few months ago I resolved this issue.